# Many combobox from one data source [Kendo]

Tags: kendo-ui

Is there any known way, how to build N-separated Comboboxes from one data source, without making new ViewModel for each Combobox, in KendoUI

Answer (score 0):

Binding multiple widgets to a single dataSource means that each time you filter or sort the dataSource each widget will accept the changes - I do not think it is a good idea.

If you want all of your widgets to use dataSource with the same settings, create an object which represents your settings and use it each time you create new dataSource for the different combos.

Comment: I have a customer list, I need to clone it on page. Click plus sign and new combobox with customers appear. And all these comboboxes should use the same data as a source to build a list. If all of them will use the same ViewModel it's not good you are right. It means if I need to have 100 lists, I should have 100 views and 100 viewmodels it is true ?

Comment: I have a similar issue where I may have 100 combo boxes on a large data entry page where, using the scenario above, a customer list must appear for each selected item. For performance reasons I'm hoping I can deduplicate the list so that each combobox uses the same object instead of cloning it 100's of times.